# Java - Sprite in JPanel error

Tags: java, jpanel, collision-detection, sprite

Every time i run the panel is filled with a white line in the corner of it and the rest is black.
I would like to add KeyListener to the program so when i push the "W" key it will animate the sprite as it seems to be going forward.

IF the sprite is not centered all the time than how would i code a collision detect to repaint the map when the sprite image block reaches the edge of the panel.

I know im asking more than one question yet im tring to figure out one problem.

How would i spawn a simple NPC at a specific location on the tiled map that has not yet been painted. Have this NPC to be intractable.

What I would like to do is have a sprite in the center of the screen. Have a tiled map in the background with collision detect depended on color squares. IF tile layer is colored red not allow to pass through IF tile layer is colored red allow to pass through If tile color yellow apply action for it is a treasure chest.

```
  public class gamePanel extends JPanel {
   private BufferedImage image;

    public gamePanel() throws IOException{
        this.setBackground(Color.red);  

    }
    public static void loadMap(Graphics g, int frame){
       try {
           BufferedImage bigImg = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\czar\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Inter\\src\\inter\\menu.jpg"));
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(gamePanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }


    }
    public static void loadSprite(Graphics g, int move_int) throws IOException{
        BufferedImage bigImg = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\czar\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Inter\\src\\inter\\sprite.jpg"));
        // The above line throws an checked IOException which must be caught.

        final int width = 25;
        final int height = 40;

        final int cols = 2;
        BufferedImage[] left_move = new BufferedImage[3];
        BufferedImage[] right_move = new BufferedImage[3];
        BufferedImage[] up_move = new BufferedImage[3];
        BufferedImage[] down_move = new BufferedImage[3];

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            if(move_int == 0){
                left_move[i] = bigImg.getSubimage(
                0 * width, 0 * height, width, height );
            }
            if(move_int == 1){
                right_move[i] = bigImg.getSubimage(
                i * width, 1 * height, width, height );
            }
            if(move_int == 2){
                up_move[i] = bigImg.getSubimage(
                i * width, 2 * height, width, height );
            }
            if(move_int == 3){
                down_move[i] = bigImg.getSubimage(
                i * width, 3 * height, width, height );
            }
        }


    }

    @Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
     try {

         loadMap(g, 0);
         loadSprite(g, 0);

     } catch (IOException ex) {
            // handle exception...
        }
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, but here is some quick help on solving your error.

This code...

```
BufferedImage[] down_move = new BufferedImage[3];
```

creates an array which can hold 3 images, namely:

down_move[0]
down_move[1]
down_move[2]

That is because arrays are zero-based. If you do:

```
System.out.println(down_move.length);
```

you will see it output 3. This is because your array only fits 3 images.

I assume you want 4 images on your array. Therefore you will need to modify your code to:

```
BufferedImage[] down_move = new BufferedImage[4];
```

This will result in 4 images, namely:

down_move[0]
down_move[1]
down_move[2]
down_move[3]

In your code you are trying to access down_move[3] in an array that only goes up to down_move[2].

Read the error: **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3**

Your image arrays have 3 indices (0, 1, and 2), and somewhere you're trying to access the 4th index (3).

Change your image array sizes to 4 instead of 3 (as shown below) and it should no longer give you this exception.

```
BufferedImage[] up_move = new BufferedImage[4];
BufferedImage[] down_move = new BufferedImage[4];
BufferedImage[] left_move = new BufferedImage[4];
BufferedImage[] right_move = new BufferedImage[4];
```

Comment: I want to hold 4 with in the Array... 0, 1, 2, 3. I put 3 in the brackets thinking that what it would count down to. 
down_move[0] down_move[1] down_move[2] down_move[3]
What purpose this is to hold an image of a specific still frame from the sprite animation.

Comment: What im having trouble doing is drawing the sprite and applying animation to it.
if(0);
g.drawImage(left_move[0], center, center, null);

If Keypressed is left arrow. Than If(0) is true. So animation is applyed by redrawing from an incremental array.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I hope it's clearer now. Your code is simply for loading the sprites, correct? You have no code to try and display the image anywhere...

Comment: Correct. Yet i had some trouble figuring out how to implement key listener into the program than draw the sprite depended on key input. This code loads the sprite frames individually into each array depended on the what key is to be pressed. i would assign numbers like 0 = left. enum suppose. Question is how would I drawImage into the center of the jpanel. Would i getWidth of sprite image and subtract that from the width of the panel divided by 2. I think that is the alogrithm to the scale of center.

Comment: You can find these things by looking around on the internet. Have a look at this for creating the key listener: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/133038-simple-keylistener/