# Java - How do you draw image in a sequence from a array of images

Tags: java, arrays, image, animation

Im trying to create a sprite class containing 3 frames in each array signifying each direction. This class will implement an actionlistener and keylistener so when i press W the class will animate the sprite moving forward drawing the image frame giving the illusion that it is walking.

I researched a few topics concerning this issue over the web, the result was a failed attempt.

I would have to initialize the current position intergers and velocity showing how fast it moves across the screen. I would need a timer class to run animation.

I would have to get rectangle bounds so i can calculate intersections between collisions. I am learning Game development and have studied basics in computer programming. Im still an amatur java programming and have compiled only a few attempt in solving my problem.

Here is where the Image is loaded. Depended on KeyEvent it changes .getImage() increments current_frame integer.

```
public class Sophia {
private int dx;
private int dy;
private int x;
private int y;

private Image img;

private Image[] sophia_down;
private Image[] sophia_left;
private Image[] sophia_right;
private Image[] sophia_up;

public Sophia(){
    x = 40;
    y = 60;

}

public void move(){
    x += dx;
    y += dy;

}

public int getX(){
    return x;
}

public int getY(){
    return y;
}

public Image getImage(){
    return img;
}

int current_frame = 0;
public int tick(){
    if(current_frame == 4)current_frame =0;

    return current_frame++;
}


public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        dx = -1; 
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_l1.png");
        sophia_left = new Image[4];
        sophia_left[0] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_l1.png").getImage();
        sophia_left[1] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_l2.png").getImage();
        sophia_left[2] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_l3.png").getImage();
        sophia_left[3] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_l4.png").getImage();
        img = sophia_left[tick()];
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        dx = 1; 

        sophia_right = new Image[4];
        sophia_right[0] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_r1.png").getImage();
        sophia_right[1] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_r2.png").getImage();
        sophia_right[2] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_r3.png").getImage();
        sophia_right[3] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_r4.png").getImage();
        img = sophia_right[tick()];

    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        dy = -1; 
        sophia_up = new Image[4];
        sophia_up[0] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_u1.png").getImage();
        sophia_up[1] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_u2.png").getImage();
        sophia_up[2] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_u3.png").getImage();
        sophia_up[3] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_u4.png").getImage();
        img = sophia_up[tick()];
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        dy = 1; 
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_d1.png");
        sophia_down = new Image[4];
        sophia_down[0] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_d1.png").getImage();
        sophia_down[1] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_d2.png").getImage();
        sophia_down[2] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_d3.png").getImage();
        sophia_down[3] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_d4.png").getImage();
        img = sophia_down[tick()];
    }

}


public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        dx = 0;
        current_frame = 0;
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        dx = 0;
        current_frame = 0;
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        dy = 0;
        current_frame = 0;
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        dy = 0;
        current_frame = 0;
    }
}
```

}

Here is where the image is drawn.

```
    public class Map extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    Timer  t;
    Sophia sophia;


    public Map(){
        addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
        setFocusable(true);
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setDoubleBuffered(true);

        sophia = new Sophia();
        npc = new NPC();

        t = new Timer(5, this);
        t.start();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.drawImage(sophia.getImage(), sophia.getX(), sophia.getY(), this);


        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();
    }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       sophia.move();
       repaint();
   }

   private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {
       public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
           sophia.keyReleased(e);
       }
       public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
           sophia.keyPressed(e);
       }
   }

}
```

Here is the main class

```
public class Zion extends JFrame {
int screenWidth = 640;
int screenHeight = 480;


public Zion(){
   Map m = new Map();
   add(m);

   setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   setSize(600,600);
   setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   setTitle("Zion - Version: 0.3");
   setResizable(false);
   setVisible(true);
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
   new Zion();

}
```

}

How do i slow down the animation. The images change to fast. There is no delay

Comment: `"... the result was a failed attempt."` -- which you have not shown us(?).

Comment: You need to know the over all frame rate of the animation and the current frame in the cycle, for example, if you were rendering 25fps, each frame in your sprite sheet would need to be displayed for 8.3 frames per animation cycle.

Comment: every 2 pixels it moves to what ever direction it increments the frame. I can load an image and display it on a Jpanel. What I cant manage to do is load an array of images and display one image per frame every 2 pixels it moved over the screen. I also dont want a trail like a string of images. I would have to dispose and repaint. Im having trouble puting code together. It would be nice if some one wrote a working example.

Comment: This is how far my study has taken me. EDITED

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25728549/java-sprite-in-jpanel-error

Comment: How do I combine the right code snippets to get what im trying to do to work? Classical Mechanics

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to slow down the animation by using a timer increment the frame as there is a separate timer that repaints in the JPanel that holds all the Graphics calls.

In this class you will end up with a sprite moveing back and forth. I even initialized a bounding box for collision dection.

```
public class NPC {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int dx;
    private int dy;

    Image npc_img;
    Image[] npc_l;
    Image[] npc_r;
    Image[] npc_d;
    Image[] npc_u;

    Rectangle boundBox;

    int current_frame = 0;
    int distance = 0;

    Timer t = new Timer(300, new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            current_frame++;
            if(current_frame == 4)current_frame = 0;

            initLeft(current_frame);

            if(dx == -1 && dy == 0)initLeft(current_frame);
            if(dx == 1 && dy == 0)initRight(current_frame);
            if(dy == -1 && dx == 0)initUp(current_frame);
            if(dy == 1 && dx == 0)initDown(current_frame);

            distance++;
            if(distance <= 5){
                dx = -1;
                dy = 0;
            }
            if(distance >= 5){
                dx = 1;
                dy = 0;
            }
            if(distance == 9)distance = 0;

        }
    });

    public int getX(){return x;}
    public int getY(){return y;}

    public void move(){
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
        boundBox = new Rectangle(x, y, 60, 60);
    }

    public Image getImage(){return npc_img;}

    public void initLeft(int frame){
        npc_l = new Image[4];
        npc_l[0] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\npc_l1.png").getImage();
        npc_l[1] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\npc_l2.png").getImage();
        npc_l[2] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\npc_l3.png").getImage();
        npc_l[3] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\npc_l4.png").getImage();
        npc_img = npc_l[frame];
    }
    public void initRight(int frame){
        npc_r = new Image[4];
        npc_r[0] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\npc_r1.png").getImage();
        npc_r[1] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\npc_r2.png").getImage();
        npc_r[2] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\npc_r3.png").getImage();
        npc_r[3] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\npc_r4.png").getImage();
        npc_img = npc_r[frame];
    }public void initDown(int frame){
        npc_d = new Image[4];
        npc_d[0] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\npc_d1.png").getImage();
        npc_d[1] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\npc_d2.png").getImage();
        npc_d[2] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\npc_d3.png").getImage();
        npc_d[3] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\npc_d4.png").getImage();
        npc_img = npc_d[frame];
    }
    public void initUp(int frame){
        npc_u = new Image[4];
        npc_u[0] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\npc_u1.png").getImage();
        npc_u[1] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\npc_u2.png").getImage();
        npc_u[2] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\npc_u3.png").getImage();
        npc_u[3] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\npc_u4.png").getImage();
        npc_img = npc_u[frame];
    }

    public void interact(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawString("Greetings", (x - 20), (y - 10));
    }

    public NPC(){
        x = 250;
        y = 250;
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Inside the JPanel Paint is called.

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.drawImage(sophia.getImage(), sophia.getX(), sophia.getY(), this);
        g2d.drawImage(npc.getImage(), npc.getX(), npc.getY(), this);
        if(sophia.boundBox.intersects(npc.boundBox))npc.interact(g);

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated Sophia class. Which is the player.

```
public class Sophia {
    private int dx;
    private int dy;
    private int x;
    private int y;

    private Image img;

    private Image[] sophia_down;
    private Image[] sophia_left;
    private Image[] sophia_right;
    private Image[] sophia_up;

    Rectangle boundBox;

    public Sophia(){
        x = 40;
        y = 60;

    }

    public void move(){
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
        boundBox = new Rectangle(x, y, 62, 62);
        t.start();
    }

    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public int getY(){
        return y;
    }

    public Image getImage(){
        return img;
    }

    int current_frame = 0;
    Timer t = new Timer(150, new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            current_frame++;
            if(current_frame == 4)current_frame = 0;
        }
    });


    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            dx = -1; 

            sophia_left = new Image[4];
            sophia_left[0] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_l1.png").getImage();
            sophia_left[1] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_l2.png").getImage();
            sophia_left[2] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_l3.png").getImage();
            sophia_left[3] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_l4.png").getImage();
            img = sophia_left[current_frame];
        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            dx = 1; 

            sophia_right = new Image[4];
            sophia_right[0] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_r1.png").getImage();
            sophia_right[1] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_r2.png").getImage();
            sophia_right[2] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_r3.png").getImage();
            sophia_right[3] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_r4.png").getImage();
            img = sophia_right[current_frame];

        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            dy = -1; 

            sophia_up = new Image[4];
            sophia_up[0] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_u1.png").getImage();
            sophia_up[1] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_u2.png").getImage();
            sophia_up[2] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_u3.png").getImage();
            sophia_up[3] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_u4.png").getImage();
            img = sophia_up[current_frame];
        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            dy = 1; 

            sophia_down = new Image[4];
            sophia_down[0] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_d1.png").getImage();
            sophia_down[1] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_d2.png").getImage();
            sophia_down[2] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_d3.png").getImage();
            sophia_down[3] = new ImageIcon("C:\\imgs\\zion\\sophia_d4.png").getImage();
            img = sophia_down[current_frame];
        }

    }


    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            dx = 0;

        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            dx = 0;

        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            dy = 0;

        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            dy = 0;

        }
    }
}
```